# What is the best way to use three different losses on two classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, optimization

Two classifiers need to be trained simultaneously, and I have three losses, as shown in the figure. Classifiers 1 and 2 will be updated by losses 1 and 2. Furthermore, loss 3 should update the two classifiers concurrently.
Here's what I did

```
loss1.backward()
loss2.backward()
loss2.backward()
```

Is this correct? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another loss $loss_T$ that combines losses $loss_1$, $loss_2$ and $loss_3$, and optimize only $loss_T$.

The typical approach is to define $loss_T = \lambda_1 \cdot loss_1 + \lambda_2 \cdot loss_2 + \lambda_3 \cdot loss_3$, where $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ are new hyper parameters (note that you can remove $\lambda_3$ to simplify and still keep the same expressivity). To give values to $\lambda_i$ you may simply assign $\lambda_i = 1$ or you can grid search to obtain better values.

Normally, you want $\lambda_i$ to compensate for the differences in the gradient norms of $loss_i$, to avoid one of them overshadowing the rest.
For that, I suggest you monitor the norm of the gradients of $loss_i$ in a  training rehearsal to understand the value ranges that are appropriate for each $\lambda_i$.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Please consider upvoting the answer and marking it as correct.